# How to fill rectangle with opacity in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I can fill rectangle with canvas draw rect:

```
Rect rt = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
myPaint.setColor(myColor);
myPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
canvas.drawRect(rt, myPaint);
```

But I need the method to fill rectangle with the opacity (in percent, with 0% is TRANSPARENT).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `Alpha` property of [Paint class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html).

`myPaint.setAlpha(10);` will help you.

Comment: It appears alpha must be set only after the style is set to FILL.  If you have the style as STROKE, add the alpha, then change it to FILL, the alpha will remain at 255 (undocumented).

Comment: Use Color with opacity if you need to use STROKE

Comment: Another thing to note is that Alpha value should range from 0 to 255

Comment: @Dorje 's comment is still valid. Does anybody have any idea why style must be set to FILL before alpha is changed???