# Stroke opacity doesn't do anything

Tags: android

I draw an Arc like this:

```
    int STEPS = 45;
    int STARTANGLE = 270;

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(200);
    // opacity
    p.setAlpha(60); //

    RectF rectF = new RectF(400, 400, 800,  800);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for(int i = STARTANGLE; i < 90/STEPS * 4 * STARTANGLE; i += STEPS) {
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, i, 45, false, p);
    }
```

The goal is to animate this but I just wrote a forloop to see if everything worked.

My opacity isn't working. Its a black stroke line, but the things that are underneath are covered up.

Can't you set the opacity of the stroke?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10348178/1777090)

Comment: When I switch p.setAlpha to 10. It doesn't do anything. Do I need to change something more on that link?

Comment: Did you try to change value to 255 and 0 alternatively?

Comment: Whatever I change the setAlpha to, nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setColor()` sets the alpha as well as the RGB values. Therefore, your call to `setColor()` is changing the alpha you previously set using `setAlpha()`.

Answer (score 0):

The link of Dhruti inspired me to change the sequence in what I do things.

You need to set the color first and then the alpha. Then it just works.

Comment: There's a reason why the change of sequence 'just works'; see my answer!